# Rotations via Rotors

Tags: rotations, geometric-algebras

I am reading this [PDF](http://www2.eng.cam.ac.uk/~rjw57/pdf/r_wareham_pdh_thesis.pdf) and have a question regarding an example which is given page $9$ with regard to using rotors to perform rotation. I made screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

As the text suggest we can write $(e_1 + e_2)B_3$ to perform a rotation of vector $e_1 + e_2$ by 90 degrees counter-clockwise so in fact the result of $(e_1 + e_2)B_3$ should be $e_2 - e_1$ as shown in the figure, though I don't understand the derivation to get this result?

$ (e_1 + e_2)B_3 = e_1 B_3 + e_2 B_3 = e_1(e_1 e_2) + e_2(e_1 e_2)$

Where $ab$ in this context is the geometric product defined as:

$ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b.$

I understand that because of associativity/communitivty you can write:

$ (e_1 + e_2)B_3 = e_1 B_3 + e_2 B_3 = e_1(e_1 e_2) + e_2(e_1 e_2) = (e_1 e_1) e_2 + e_1 (e_2 e_2)$

Is that correct? and how do I get to the final result $e_2 - e_1$?

The scalar product of a vector with itself is 1 (assuming the vector is of unit length) but I am not too sure what the vector product of a vector with itself is (it should be the vector 0,0,0 if the vector has three-dimensions, right?).

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthogonal vectors *anti*commute.  So $$e_2(e_1e_2) = -e_2(e_2e_1) = -(e_2e_2)e_1 = -(1)e_1 = -e_1$$

Comment: If you'd like more of a run-down of how the geometric product works just let me know.  Otherwise I'll assume this very short answer is sufficient.

Comment: I think I get it. Though I assume this applies to the geometric product or is the change of sign due to the fact that the vector product contained in the geometric product is anti commutative, hence the change in sign? $e_1e_2 = e_1 \cdot e_2 + e_1 \wedge e_2 \rightarrow e_2e_1 = e_1 \cdot e_2 - e_2 \wedge e_1$ hence we can write $e_1e_2 = -e_2e_1$ (and since the vectors are orthogonal the scalar product is 0). Is that correct?

Comment: Yep.  That's right.